# Does AbstractionAction's putValue() method work with subclasses of JMenuItem, etc?

Tags: java, swing

Maybe it's a bad idea, but I wrote a subclass for [JMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) to add a new constructor. Let's call it `JMenuItemX`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JMenuItemX extends JMenuItem
{
  public JMenuItemX(final String the_text, final char the_mnemonic,
                    final ActionListener the_action)
  {
    super(the_text);
    setMnemonic(the_mnemonic);
    addActionListener(the_action);
  }
}
```

---

Now, I am trying to add a tooltip to the component by using [AbstractAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AboutAction extends AbstractAction
{

  public AboutAction()
  {
    super("About");
    putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Show the popup window");
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent the_event)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");
  }
}
```

and constructing the component as so (the JFrame, JMenuBar, and JMenu are already set up):

```
menu.add(new JMenuItemX("About", 'a', new AboutAction()));
```

*(As you can see, if I am adding multiple menu items, this single-line format is easier to read.)*

---

The menu item is visible with the correct text, and the mnemonic and action work as expected. But there is no tooltip... However, if I simply use JMenuItem, the tooltip works!

```
JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem(new AboutAction());
about.setMnemonic('a');
menu.add(about);
```

---

How can I get AbstractAction to work with my JMenuItem subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your overridden constructor doesn't use the JMenuItem constructor taking an Action as argument, and doesn't call `setAction()` either. So your menu item is not associated to the action.

I would not create a subclass just to add a constructor. Why not simply create a factory method?

```
public JMenuItem createMenuItemWithListener(String text, 
                                            char mnemonic, 
                                            ActionListener action) {
    JMenuItem result = new JMenuItem(text);
    result.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
    result.addActionListener(action);
    return result;
}

public JMenuItem createMenuItemWithAction(char mnemonic, 
                                          Action action) {
    JMenuItem result = new JMenuItem(action);
    result.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have realized that `JMenuItem(action)` was not the same as `JMenuItem.addActionListener()`.